# text cut by the top on windows chrome and windows firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, font-size

I've checked cross-browser and everything works well except on windows machine. Strangely IE looks fine but chrome and firefox on a windows machine has a strange effect on the menu items. The text is cut from above as you can see in this text.

The font-size is of 12px, If I change the font-size to 13px or 11px the problem is solved, but I do not want to change the font size. Is there another trick I could use? Has anybody had this problem before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

css and html code would have been helpfull, try `line-height:3%` or `padding-top:5px;` 
customise values for attribute if it works!

Comment: i removed the font-family you were using and changed the font-size to 12px, its works just fine,change `font-family: telegrafico,serif;` in style.css **nav** attrib to some other font family and check

Comment: I see this could be the fault, the font on web does not work correctly with 12px. The solution shouldn't be to change the font as that is used in all the navigation. I changed the pixel size from one pixel and it worked, not what I wished for but if I have to choose between changing the font-family or the font-size I will fo for changing the font-size by 1 px.

Comment: please dont duplicate the questions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996913/quote-element-cut-by-half-on-ie

Comment: This is not a duplicate question, this problem is with the menu bar, the other question has a complete different effect with the quote element.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found for now is **changing the font size by one pixel**. So at this moment the font is `font-size:13px;` It works... but I would like to find another solution as maybe one day I won;t have the option of changing the font size due to a tight design. Please let me know if anybody has different solution for this.